# Update Joda-Time in Grails

Tags: grails, jodatime, localtime

I use Joda-Time via joda-time plugin in Grails to input time data, but its constructor shows time, which is one hour ahead then in my time zone. Compulsory timezone setting in constructor as like:

```
new LocalTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Moscow"))
```

doesn't help.

I've heard, what it happens, because I've outdated timezone data containing old dst rules. And I must to update it to newest version v2.8, which would probably help against old data. How to do it if I use newest joda-time plugin in Grails, which was updated last July.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `BuildConfig.groovy`, try

```
dependencies {
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:x.y"  // x.y is the version of interest, make sure it's compatible with the plugin
}
plugins {
    compile ":joda-time:1.5" {
        excludes "joda-time" 
    }
}
```

Ref: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/single.html#pluginDependencies